# 'fatal error' during bundle install in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems, bundler, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I Have This in my GemFile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem "nested_form", :git => "https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git" 
gem 'lazy_high_charts', :git => "https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts.git"


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

And when i try to bundle install...i get the following Error

```
Updating https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts.git
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please report this error to the Bundler issue tracker at https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues so that we can fix it. Please in
clude the full output of the command, your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock. Thanks!
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre/lib/bundler/source.rb:578:in ``': No such file or directory - git fetch --force --quiet --tags "https://github.com/michel
son/lazy_high_charts.git" "refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*" (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre/lib/bundler/source.rb:578:in `git'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre/lib/bundler/source.rb:533:in `block in checkout'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre/lib/bundler/source.rb:620:in `chdir'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre/lib/bundler/source.rb:620:in `in_path'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre/lib/bundler/source.rb:532:in `checkout'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre/lib/bundler/source.rb:760:in `specs'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre/lib/bundler/definition.rb:486:in `block in converge_locked_specs'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre/lib/bundler/definition.rb:475:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre/lib/bundler/definition.rb:475:in `converge_locked_specs'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166:in `resolve'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre/lib/bundler/definition.rb:113:in `specs'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre/lib/bundler/definition.rb:108:in `resolve_remotely!'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre/lib/bundler/installer.rb:81:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre/lib/bundler/installer.rb:14:in `install'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre/lib/bundler/cli.rb:224:in `install'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0.pre/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

And if i take out these two lines....

```
:git => "https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git" 
:git => "https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts.git"
```

The bundle install happens perfectly....what seems to be the problem?? how can i fix it???i am Using Windows 7. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a way to bypass, you can download these gems and specify the path to them `:path => "/path/to/gem"`. As for fix, check your git installation, try to reinstall rails, using rails installer... This is windows, usually there is no obvious way to fix the bug )

Comment: Thanks Mikhail i did reinstall now everything is working fine :)

Answer (score 1):

FWIW:

In my case it boiled down to the shell not finding the `git` binaries.

I opened a **GitHub Shell**, since i had installed the **GitHub Client**, and `bundle install` this time worked flawlessly.